# Boolberry's Transaction identification by prefix

Tags: scalability, boolberry

Boolberry has a feature named **transaction identification by prefix**, which allows to "cut ring signatures from the blockchain reducing block chain size by 60-90%, depending on mixin usage." Is this compatible with every CN coin? Does it have any disadvantages?

For more information on transaction [identificiation by prefix](http://boolberry.com/files/Boolberry_Reduces_Blockchain_Bloat.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just took a look at the *get_transaction_hash* function in the Monero source code, and if I understand it correctly, the way the transaction hash is computed will change once ringct is activated.

The comments in the code indicate:

- v1 transactions hash the entire blob
- v2 transactions hash different parts together, then hash the set of those hashes

The 3 parts of v2 transactions are:

- prefix
- base rct
- prunable rct

Hashing the hashes of these 3 parts together gives the final transaction hash.

I suppose pruning the signature from the block chain will be possible (like in Boolberry), because keeping the hashes of the signature parts instead of the whole signature will still allow computing the transaction hash.

Comment: You are correct. The pruning isn't done yet, but this is preparatory work.